# Can anyone identify this spreading weed?

Tags: identification, lawn, weeds

This weed is all over my landscape and yard. It spreads like grass. It blends in with my St. Augustine grass and ends up in pots that are setting on the ground. I've tried Roundup and broadleaf weed killers and neither seem to work. I've used MSMA and it seemed to have an affect on it, but not permanent.

[image]

Comment: Your post had two image links, https://i.stack.imgur.com/olpVU.jpg and https://i.stack.imgur.com/16If7.png, but both appear to be the same image. Did you mean to post a different one?

Comment: I cannot identify (main question), but this is not a broadleaf. You may look in this forum on how to get rid of bamboos (an other very difficult monocots), if the roots are the problems. You may need also to look for seed sources nearby you